# Python error: NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') on Centos 7 but not Centos 5

Tags: python, numpy, centos7, centos5

I'm having an issue where numpy (I believe) is breaking float64 on my CentOS 7 machine but not my Centos 5 machine (same script run on each machine). This is quite bizarre as they both access the same anaconda install in a networked home dir. Something is broken on my CentOS 7 machine. Why would one machine have numerical errors while another wouldn't when the python install is identical?

Comment: Perhaps they are running different python programs.  Perhaps only one has a bug.

Comment: When you installed Anaconda into your shared home directory, the C extensions for numpy, scipy etc will have been natively compiled for whichever machine you were using at the time. Perhaps the error is caused by some incompatibility between that machine and the one you are using now. Using the exact same Python environment across multiple non-identical machines sounds like a recipe for trouble.

Comment: That is strange. Have you tried to run the numpy and scipy test suites on both machines to make sure there is no installation issues? @ali_m Anaconda ships pre-compiled  binary packages (for either 32 or 64 bits) so it should not matter so much where it was  installed it in the first place, since no machine-specific compilation takes place.

Comment: @rth I didn't realise that (I don't normally use Anaconda myself). Would the same also be true for additional packages installed using `conda`? Also, if Anaconda is cross-platform then it would presumably have fetched binaries appropriate to the machine that was used to install it. If you have two different machines using the same binaries then there might still potentially be issues arising from cross-platform incompatibilities, e.g. if one is 32bit and the other 64.